# Select return 0 but data can be read

Tags: c, linux, sockets, system-calls

I'm trying to understand the select() system call on Linux. To do so I wrote a smal program that will open a server and client socket. The client socket will be created in a newly created thread. The client will send around 90byte of data to the server (just a test string). Before reading from the server socket, I execute a select() with a timeout of 60 seconds.

My problem now is: select will timeout every time. I checked that my select call is correct (i set the FD_Set right before the call), I ensured that the server fd is set and I choose a large enough timeout so that normal scheduling should not interfere with it. Yet, for some reason I cannot get select to work properbly.

My code is as follows (for debugging i read regardless of what select() returns):

```
struct timeval tv = {
    .tv_sec = 60,
    .tv_usec = 0,
};    
printf("[+] Creating server socket!\n");
if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
{ 
    // set error and exit
} 
if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
{ 
    // set error and exit
} 
if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address_block, sizeof(address_block))<0) 
{ 
    // set error and exit
} 

//Create client thread here
pthread_create(&p2, NULL, client_function, NULL);

if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
{ 
    // set error and exit
} 

if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
{ 
    // set error and exit
} 

printf("\t[select] Non-Blocking Server fd is: %d\n", server_fd);

//create and set fds_non_blocking set    
FD_ZERO(&fds_non_blocking);
FD_SET(server_fd, &fds_non_blocking);


int select_return = select(server_fd + 1, &fds_non_blocking, NULL, NULL, &tv);

valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
```

(Note: I know i should check if select return is >0 and which FD is set). The function "client_function()" does something similar and then sends a string. It will sleep for 3 seconds, and will always send the data after select() was started.

When executing this program, select will always timeout and the read after select will always receive the data send by the client.

Can anybody see my mistake here? I already compared my implementation with other (most often the error was that the first select argument was not set to "Server fd + 1"). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: btw, _On Linux, select() modifies timeout to reflect the amount of time not slept_. you need to reset tv each time before calling select()

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Did know this until now. Any idea for the reason of my problem?

Comment: you need to add new_socket to fds_non_blocking for select to detect read on new socket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select for `new_socket`, not for `server_fd`:

```
FD_ZERO(&fds_non_blocking);
FD_SET(new_socket, &fds_non_blocking);

int select_return = select(new_socket + 1, &fds_non_blocking, NULL, NULL, &tv);

valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024);
```

If you want to check both filedescriptors simultaneously, you can use

```
FD_ZERO(&fds_non_blocking);
FD_SET(new_socket, &fds_non_blocking);
FD_SET(server_fd, &fds_non_blocking);

int maxfd = (server_fd > new_socket)?server_fd+1:new_socket+1;   
int select_return = select(maxfd, &fds_non_blocking, NULL, NULL, &tv);

if (FD_ISSET(new_socket, &fds_non_blocking))
    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
else if (FD_ISSET(server_fd, &fds_non_blocking))
    ; // Accept a new client
```

Otherwise, you will only look for new client connections to accept, not for pending data on the accepted socket.

Furthermore, you have to reset the timeval struct after each call to `select()`. The values there are updated by the kernel to reflect the remaining time not spent waiting.

Comment: Thank you! I did a copy&paste error here apparently. But this fixed it!